# Programmatically submit a form from an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

In my Angular 1.5.X app I have a directive with the following template

```
<form id="pdfDownloadForm"
      name='pdfDownloadForm'
      method="POST"
      action="{{ downloadUrl }}">          

  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="" />   
  <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, I would like to do the following

1. Set the value of the hidden parameter `data` to a value retrieved from a remote service
2. Submit the form

### Attempted Solution

Presumably the easiest way to set the hidden parameter is with

```
<input type="hidden" name="data" ng-model="dataValue" />
```

and then before submitting the form, assign to `scope.dataValue` the value retrieved from the remote service?

I tried to submit the form programmatically with

```
scope.submit = function () {    
    $('#pdfDownloadForm').submit();
}
```

But this causes the following error:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Comment: Try `$timeout(function(){$('#pdfDownloadForm').submit();})` in order to get rid of the error. Remember _inject_ the `$timeout` service;

Comment: why are you using a function bound in angular to call a jquery function?  surely this isn't the *only thing* that the `$scope.submit` function is doing?

Comment: @Claies it isn't, but I only want to include the code relevant to my problem

Comment: I feel like you are approaching this in the wrong way.  The standard way to do this in angular, when you have additional tasks to do before submitting, is to not submit the **form** at all.  Instead, use a controller function to handle your processing, then submit your **data** using the `$http` service.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Angular 1.5+, there's no reason to use scope - either use `controllerAs` syntax or, preferably, [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03).

I'd implement your task by interrupting first submit call and populating hidden field instead.  Any subsequent submits are allowed to happen.

```js
// inside contorller

onSubmit(event) {
  if (!this.dataValue) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.initializeData();
  }
}

initializeData() {
    $http.get('/my-data-source').then((response) => {
        this.dataValue = response.data.value;
        this.pdfDownloadForm.submit(); // requires <form name="$ctrl.pdfDownloadForm">
    });
}
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

It's better to avoid using ngClick here since form can be submitted by Enter instead of button click.

Comment: I don't think I can use the `controllerAs` syntax, because I don't have a controller - my directive only has a link function. Thanks for mentioning components, I'll read up on them.

Answer (score 0):

`<button type="button" ng-click="submit">Submit</button>`

should be

`<button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>`

---

so after your edit to your post, this wasn't the solution? have your tried it?